# Why can we do limit manipulation on one limit but not the other?

Tags: calculus, limits

For example:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (x)^{\frac{1}{x-1}} \neq (\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (x))^{\frac{1}{x-1}} \equiv 1$$

But when we talk about euler limits (the example may not be accurate, but there are a lot of limits that do this):

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (1+ \frac{1}{x-1})^{x^2-1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (1+ \frac{1}{x-1})^{(x+1)(x-1)} = e^{ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1}x+1} = e^2$$

Meaning that we calculate the base of the power, getting that number $e$ and then proceeding to calculate the exponent power $e^{\lim ~ \dots}$

What is the actual difference here? Why in the first one I can't calculate the base of the power and in euler limits I can? I really don't get it.. Thanks!

Comment: Your first formula doesn't make sense. In
$$\left(\lim_{x\to1} x\right)^{\frac1{x-1}}$$
what is the value of $x$ in the exponent?

Comment: @JackM The examples may not be accurate but, why can we calculate $e$ before everything else but not in other occasions? The first solution comes because 1 to the power of anything is 1, but indeed that is not correct, so why can we do the same when we talk about $e^{\text{something}}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the limit is of the form $1^\infty$ which is indeterminate.  In the second case, you're skipping a step.  We have $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \left(1+ \frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{(x+1)(x-1)}=
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\left(1+ \frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{x-1}\right)^{x+1}$$ and the limit of the base is $e$, the limit of the exponent is $2$, and there's no indeterminacy.

Comment: So if the base of the first limit wasn't 1 but another number, i.e 2 or 5/103 then we could do the same thing? by calculating the base of the exponent before the whole thing?

Comment: Provided the limit of the base and the limit of the exponent exist, and the limit of the base is a positive number different from $1$.